# How can I get the dock badge text of *other* applications?

Tags: swift, macos

I am making a macOS Dock application for myself, but now I'm stuck.

How to get the badge count of all other applications?

Or, I want to know, how does Swift monitor the macOS system notification events? So I can update a red spot to notice that users there are getting new notifications.

I am using the uBar Dock, I see it can take the badge count for all running applications. I can't figure it out how to do this.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: I thought these might show up in the accessibility API, but after poking around with Accessibility Inspector, it doesn't seem like its exposed there. Not sure how they do it then. I wouldn't be surprised if uBar is using some private API on LaunchServices or something like that.

Comment: Ding ding ding, I found that the badge text is listened under the `"StatusLabel"` key if you run `lsappinfo -all list`. https://eclecticlight.co/2020/03/04/learn-almost-everything-about-an-app-with-lsappinfo/ I couldn't find a native API to get at that information directly, but I also didn't search very hard. Worse-case scenario, you can call out to the `lsappinfo` program and parse the output, though I'd try pretty hard to avoid that, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proof-of-concept script that shows that it is possible, using private LaunchServices APIs. I did it in a Python script (which uses PyObjC, `pip3 install PyObjC`) because it's a bit easier to capture in a single code block, and it's easier to hack around compared to a mess of headers, `dlopen` calls, etc.

This is probably the same as what `lsappinfo` does internally.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#ref: https://gist.github.com/pudquick/eebc4d569100c8e3039bf3eae56bee4c

from Foundation import NSBundle
import objc
CoreServices = NSBundle.bundleWithIdentifier_('com.apple.CoreServices')

functions = [
    ('_LSCopyRunningApplicationArray', b'@I'),
    ('_LSCopyApplicationInformation', b'@I@@'),
]

constants = [
    ('_kLSDisplayNameKey', b'@'),
]

objc.loadBundleFunctions(CoreServices, globals(), functions)
objc.loadBundleVariables(CoreServices, globals(), constants)


kLSDefaultSessionID = 0xfffffffe # The actual value is `int -2`
badge_label_key = "StatusLabel" # TODO: Is there a `_kLS*` constant for this?

app_asns = _LSCopyRunningApplicationArray(kLSDefaultSessionID)
app_infos = [_LSCopyApplicationInformation(kLSDefaultSessionID, asn, None) for asn in app_asns]

app_badges = { app_info.get(_kLSDisplayNameKey): app_info[badge_label_key].get("label", None)
    for app_info in app_infos if badge_label_key in app_info }

print(app_badges)
```

Inspired by @Ranoiaetep's answer, here's how I would write this in Swift:

```swift
import Foundation
import CoreFoundation

let CoreServiceBundle = CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier("com.apple.CoreServices" as CFString)

typealias LSASN = CFTypeRef
let kLSDefaultSessionID: Int32 = -2
let badgeLabelKey = "StatusLabel" // TODO: Is there a `_kLS*` constant for this?

typealias _LSCopyRunningApplicationArray_Type = @convention(c) (Int32) -> [LSASN]

let _LSCopyRunningApplicationArray: _LSCopyRunningApplicationArray_Type = {
    let untypedFnPtr = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(CoreServiceBundle, "_LSCopyRunningApplicationArray" as CFString)
    return unsafeBitCast(untypedFnPtr, to: _LSCopyRunningApplicationArray_Type.self)
}()

typealias _LSCopyApplicationInformation_Type = @convention(c) (Int32, CFTypeRef, CFString?) -> [CFString: CFDictionary]

let _LSCopyApplicationInformation: _LSCopyApplicationInformation_Type = {
    let untypedFnPtr = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(CoreServiceBundle, "_LSCopyApplicationInformation" as CFString)
    return unsafeBitCast(untypedFnPtr, to: _LSCopyApplicationInformation_Type.self)
}()

func getAllAppASNs() -> [LSASN] {
    _LSCopyRunningApplicationArray(kLSDefaultSessionID)
}

func getAppInfo(asn: LSASN, property: String? = nil) -> [String: Any] {
    _LSCopyApplicationInformation(kLSDefaultSessionID, asn, property as CFString?) as [String: Any]
}


let apps = getAllAppASNs()
let appInfos = apps.map { getAppInfo(asn: $0) }

let appBadges = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: 
    appInfos.compactMap { appInfo -> (key: String, value: String)? in
        guard let badgeLabel = appInfo[badgeLabelKey] else { return nil }
        
        // It's posisble to make apps with no bundle
        let appName = appInfo[kCFBundleNameKey as String] as! String? ?? "<no bundle name>"
        let badgeString = (badgeLabel as! [String: String])["label"]!
        
        return (key: appName, value: badgeString)
    }
)

appBadges.forEach { k, v in print("\(k): '\(v)'")}
```

You can test it easily by making a minimal app with a badge label, like so:

```swift
import AppKit

NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
NSApplication.shared.dockTile.badgeLabel = "123"

NSApplication.shared.run()
```

Interestingly, such an app won't have a bundle (and thus no bundle name), which is why I put `?? "<no bundle name>"` above.

Comment: I was able to rewrite this into Swift code, however seems like badges from system apps that are able to update in the background, such as **Messages** and **FaceTime** won't be detected with this method. While haven't tested your code, but I would assume the same.

Answer (score 2):

***@Alexander*** already provided an answer in python with `PyObjC` library, here is basically just rewriting that answer with Swift using [CFBundle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfbundle-s0a):

```swift
let CoreServiceBundle = CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier("com.apple.CoreServices" as CFString)

let GetRunningApplicationArray: () -> [CFTypeRef] = {
    let functionPtr = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(CoreServiceBundle, "_LSCopyRunningApplicationArray" as CFString)
    return unsafeBitCast(functionPtr,to:(@convention(c)(UInt)->[CFTypeRef]).self)(0xfffffffe)
}

let GetApplicationInformation: (CFTypeRef) -> [String:CFTypeRef] = { app in
    let functionPtr = CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(CoreServiceBundle, "_LSCopyApplicationInformation" as CFString)
    return unsafeBitCast(functionPtr, to: (@convention(c)(UInt, Any, Any)->[String:CFTypeRef]).self)(0xffffffff, app, 0)
}

let badgeLabelKey = "StatusLabel"

let apps = GetRunningApplicationArray()
let appInfos = apps.map { GetApplicationInformation($0) }

let appBadges = appInfos
    .filter{ $0.keys.contains(badgeLabelKey) }
    .reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1[kCFBundleNameKey as String] as! String] = ($1[badgeLabelKey] as! [String:CFTypeRef])["label"] }

print(appBadges)
```

---

One thing to note is that it seems like badges from system apps that are able to update badge while not being active, such as **Messages**, **FaceTime**, **System Settings**, won't be detected through this method. And I would assume the same with ***@Alexander***'s answer.

Comment: This is fantastic work! I didn't know about `CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName`. One critique though: It might be confusing if your wrapper around `_LSCopyApplicationInformation` has a different type. I'd suggest keeping the original names as more direct mappings onto the private APIs, then making separately named helpers for your own use. Also, the return and param types here aren't `CFBundle`. `CFGetTypeID(apps.first)` returns `73`, but `CFBundle`'s type ID is `31` (`CFBundleGetTypeID()`). They're a private type called LSASN, which we can refer to just as a generic `CFTypeRef`

Comment: Check out the update to my answer, where I corrected the types and incorporated the suggestion I just mentioned

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for the critics. I have updated the names for the wrappers to `GetXXX` to avoid using the original name as suggested. Also I had no idea `CFTypeRef` exist, or maybe I should just use `Any` instead.

Comment: `CFTypeRef` is like the `Any` of Core Foundation, as `NSObject` (erm the protocol, imported into Swift as `NSObjectProtocol) is to Foundation

Comment: Oh btw one other thing to note is that your 2 functions are doing a dlopen on everycall. Might not be an issue if they're not call too often, but caching the casted functions might be worth it

Comment: This code leaks memory I'm pretty sure. How do you free this unsafe memory when you're done with it?